# Can an mvc razor @helper return a non-encoded tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is contrived, but its basically what I'm doing. I have an a @helper like so:

```
@helper MyImage(int i) {
    String s = "<img src='{0}' />";
    String theImage = "";
    switch(i) {
        case 0: theImage = "test1.png"; break;
        case 1: theImage = "test2.png"; break;
        default: theImage = "error.png"; break;
    }
    String r = String.Format(s, theImage);
    @(r)
}
```

The output I get on the web page is of course the actual string:

```
<img src='test1.png' />
```

instead of the image. Is there a way to disable it from encoding it that way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `@Html.Raw(r)` rather than just `@(r)`.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx

```
@(new MvcHtmlString(r))
```

Comment: I didn't mark yours as the answer, even though it does accomplish the same thing, as I felt LukeH's answer was more succinct.